# Is there a communication limit for REST Request and Response in Outlook Add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-app

I'm building an Outlook add-in using Office.js, and I'm using REST to communicate with external applications.
Are any of the following limitations present in the Outlook add-in?

- Capacity of POST requests
- Number of REST sends and receives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfficeJS doesn't have any limitation on the number of REST calls or capacity. You just need to keep in mind CORS restrictions.

The same-origin policy enforced by the browser prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. For example, this policy will prevent a webpage in one domain from making `XmlHttpRequest` web-service calls to a domain other than the one where it is hosted. Read more about that in the  [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article.